# tomcatとの接続でタイムアウトする

Tags: apache

AWSにて踏み台とインターネット経由（ALB）で参照可能なCMSサーバを構築しています。
開発者は踏み台経由、使用者はインターネット経由での接続を想定しております。
インターネット経由の場合、ログインし、詳細ページを開くと以下のエラーが発生し参照できません。
踏み台経由ではエラーとならず参照可能です。

踏み台経由での接続時は参照できるためアプリ側の問題ではないと判断していますが
インターネット経由ではタイムアウトする理由・対応方法をご教授ください。

**実行環境:**

Apache:2.4.6
tomcat：8.5.34
Java：11

**実施したが改善されなかった対応**

- Proxypassに「Keepalive=on」を設定
- timeoutと同じ値をProxyTimeoutに設定
- MaxKeepAliveRequestsを100から200に設定
- KeepAliveTimeoutを5から60に設定

error.log

```
[Fri Jun 11 17:57:53.789818 2021] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 23603:tid 139646499485440] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01030: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header
```

追加情報が必要でしたらご連絡ください。

Comment: Tomcatの`server.xml`で定義している`Connector`要素の`timeout`属性の値はいくつになっていますか? (単位はミリ秒です)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。  
Connector要素のTimeout値は600000となっています。 設定内容は以下です   <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3"  
  useBodyEncodingForURI="true" enableLookups="false" proxyPort="443"  
  scheme="https" secure="true" maxPostSize="10485760"  
  connectionTimeout="600000" /> ほかのTimeout値も600（秒）になっております